# Why do I fall through the map in Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I play Skyrim and I walk around in the Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary, I fall through the floor when go through a hallway. Why does this happen?

Comment: because skyrim is buggy as heck

Comment: On what platform? Console? PC? Do you have the latest updates and [USKP](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Unofficial_Skyrim_Patch) installed?

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is, there is geometry missing in the map.

The simple solution is, avoid that area where you fall through.